# Styling submit buttons -- Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have been trying to put a font awesome or glyphicon (or even an image) inside a submit button. This quickly falls apart, and I need to implement another option. I have seen a few ways of doing this, but I don't know which is the "right" or better way.

The three contenders I've seen are:

- divs
- links
- buttons

Which is the best way to get an image / icon inside a "submit" button?

Wouldn't all three need a JS component?

Comment: Should this be on "Programmers Exchange" instead?

Comment: Okay. I think some have said things like, "If you make a link submit the form, it won't work on clients who don't run JS."

Comment: Check how bootstrap add glyphicon to button element http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-examples

Comment: @Jeff - No, this doesn't belong on programmers as it's more about an implementation issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how bootstrap add glyphicon to button object:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> Star
</button>
```

[Bootstrap button with glyphicon](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-examples)

Comment: And you would have to use JS to submit with a button like that right? Is this okay to do?

Comment: no need of JS to submit. Replicate bootstrap css into your project to mimic this style of button and I think it will do the job.

Comment: I'm currently using this code and the buttons do nothing.

Comment: replace type="button" by type="submit"

Answer (score 1):

The button option does not need JS. I have tested it and you can see a working example using Font Awesome here https://jsfiddle.net/mikhailjan/sf9s28et/5/ or just see the code below:

```
<form action="add_person.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>

  <button type="submit" class="button">
    <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Add Person
  </button>

</form>
```

Jonathan Anctil is correct, the button needs to have `type="submit"` for the form to work normally.